# ReentrantLock VS ReentrantReadWriteLock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I was wondering what the difference is between `ReentrantLock` and `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, in terms of logical difference. In other words, are there situations when you just need a lock without read/write locks and vice versa, read/write locks and just a lock is not sufficient?

Consider the following primary example that uses just a lock:

```
public class Counter {

  private int counter = 0;
  private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

  public void increment() {
    lock.lock();
    counter += 1;
    lock.unlock();
  }

  public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
  }
}
```

Consider, and compare it against the previous one, the following read/write lock example:

```
public class Counter {

  private int counter = 0;
  private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);

  public void increment() {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
      counter += 1;
    } finally {
      lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
  }

  public int getCounter() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
      return counter;
    } finally {
      lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Which of the two is the correct implementation in terms of thread-safety? And why?

Comment: With a `ReadWriteLock`, the read lock is shared while the write lock is exclusive. In other words, multiple threads can read at the same time so long as no thread is writing and no thread can write while one or more threads are reading. Use a `ReadWriteLock` when you need this functionality. On the other hand, a `Lock` is mutually exclusive.

Comment: Note that your first example, with the `Lock`, is not thread safe because the read of `counter` is not guarded by the `Lock`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReentrantLock` or `ReentrantReadWriteLock` depends on the use case you like to solve.

At your first example there is no lock at the `getCounter()` method. So getting the counter is possible while a thread holds the `ReentrantLock` at the increment method.

At your second example you can't get the counter while a thread holds the `writeLock()` at the increment method. And holding a `readLock()` prevents the counter increment. `readLock()` may be held simultaneously by several threads reading your `counter` param.

Comment: Re, "getting the counter is possible" Java guarantees that the unsynchronized `getCounter()` will return either the initial value of the `counter` variable or, some value that was stored into it. But without synchronization, there is _no_ guarantee of how up-to-date that value might be. It is possible (however unlikely) that on some platform, an unsynchronized  `getCounter()` call could return the initial value in one thread after some other thread had called `increment()` thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

`ReentrantReadWriteLock` can provide higher performance when the read operations are more than write operations by controlling the `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$state` carefully.

If not, the overhead of controlling is higher than `ReentrantLock`.

For your first example, it is right that you don't need to consider the atomicity problem for `getCounter()` method ,but the visibility problem should be considered. A thread may see the initial value even if other thread have incremented the counter.

Comment: Would you please shed some light on the *visibility problem*.